# ActionBar tabs are split stacked, even when there is enough space on the main bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to get the Tabs to be on the main ActionBar, like they show on [the Android Developers site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)

[image]

I wrote this basic code:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this).setText("TAB LEFT");
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this).setText("TAB CENTER");
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this).setText("TAB RIGHT");
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {}
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {}
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {}

}
```

But it shows this instead (tabs are split into a stacked action bar):

[image]

The site states:

> ...the system adapts the action bar tabs for different screen
>   sizes—placing them in the main action bar **when the screen is
>   sufficiently wide**, or in a separate bar (known as the "stacked action
>   bar") when the screen is too narrow, as shown in figures 9 and 10.

I think the screen is sufficiently wide to put the whole action bar on the main bar. I event tried defining only one tab but it still gets its own stacked bar.
I have the API Demos, but I haven't been able to locate the "Honeycomb Gallery" sample they mention, so I can examine their code.
I also tried to set the ActionBar navigation mode to STANDARD and LIST, but to no avail.

Comment: Does it work when you rotate the screen to landscape ?

Comment: @StephaneMathis Yes, in landscape mode it works. So, does it give you a hint of what's going on?

Comment: I think it's just that Android consider that it's not a good idea to display tabs in the ActionBar with a phone in portrait. It's done in order to save space on the screen, but saving vertical space on a really higher than wider screen is useless.

Comment: If you always whant your tabs in the ActionBar, you could force what you want by putting a custom view in the action bar and just managing everything yourself.

Comment: @StephaneMathis On one hand, you might be right about Android. On the other hand, the documentation does not say a thing that in portrait mode the ActionBar rules change. I started to search about custom view, It means I will have to replicate TABs look and mimic tabs behavior, it does not please me, to do so much work because of a buggy implementation (Yes, I call it a bug when the specification says it should fit on the main ActionBar but instead it does not). And finally, what is useless or not uselss, depends on the application to program, you cannot assume it upfront.

Comment: The doc says `is sufficiently wide`, so. They can do what they want. You could use a ViewPager with fragments, the ViewPagerIndicator library (http://viewpagerindicator.com/). It would be so much work.

Comment: @StephaneMathis Thanks for your efforts to help me cope. Don't lower yourself to defend Android at all costs, it is clear that they meant portrait to include tabs on the main bar too, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar , figure 3 and the paragraph before it: `That is, if you use navigation tabs in your action bar, once the action items are separated on a narrow screen, the navigation tabs may be able to fit into the main action bar...`. Sometimes it seems Android is coded by real people, with flaws and all :-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Action Bar tab policy changed last year to ALWAYS stack the tabs for ALL screen sizes in portrait mode (and before one knee-jerks why it is working otherwise for them, please read further!) even if it may fit in the Action Bar. This doesn't seem to have been well documented (or documented at all that I can find). I can confirm that this new policy is definitely being applied in JB devices if the target API version is JB.

Found this in the commit notes of the source tree

[ActionBar tabs policy commit comments in source tree](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b8139af3dcae80c0030afd0354dc424a7c72c3d9)

> Action bar tabs now stack in portrait mode on all screen sizes rather
>   than display embedded. This only affects apps with a targetSdkVersion
>   of JB or greater, as older apps may not be prepared for the different
>   measurement of the bar or have an appropriate stacked bar background
>   drawable.
>
> Stacked action bar tabs now have a width limit. This prevents
>   super-wide tabs that can span the whole screen. The cluster of tabs
>   is centered if it does not span the full width.

So if you must have the tabs embedded in the Action Bar when it fits in the portrait mode, then it appears you would have to make the target API version less than JB (which means the app cannot use any JB or later APIs) or deal with the stacked layout as the only option in portrait mode on any device regardless of the required width for the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly straightforward (well, less hackish) way now. You need to use the appcompat-v7 and design libraries (version 22.0+). I assume you use a `ViewPager` for the tab contents (if not, simply leave out the `ViewPager`-related stuff in the code below and replace it with your own tab switching logic). Have your activity extend `AppCompatActivity` (it has both the support `ActionBar` and the `ViewPager` functionality built in), then do the following in its `onCreate()` method:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    Context ctx = new ContextThemeWrapper(getApplication(), R.style.AppTheme);
    mTabLayout = new TabLayout(ctx);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams mTabLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mTabLayout.setLayoutParams(mTabLayoutParams);

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab newTab = mTabLayout.newTab();
        // Assuming you use icons on tabs (text should work, too)
        newTab.setIcon(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageIcon(i));
        mTabLayout.addTab(newTab);
    }

    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(mTabLayout);

    // This will keep tabs and the ViewPager in sync
    // (selecting a tab will switch pages, swiping will update tabs)
    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));
```

This works by instantiating a `TabLayout()` and adding it to the `ActionBar` as a custom view.

As far as I can tell, this will hide the app icon and title. I haven't yet figured out how to show them if you decide you need them, but I suppose you could always create a `LinearLayout`, drop the `TabLayout` and anything else you want on it, and pass this as the custom view.